# Suppressing warnings in the source with pragma when compiling with g++

Tags: g++, warnings, pragma

Visual Studio provides [#pragma warning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2c8f766e(v=vs.80).aspx) in the source to suppress the warnings.

Does gcc provide similar feature? I found that I can use `-fdiagnostics-show-option` to know how to get the option to disable the warning, and use command line to suppress warning, but I'd like to use pragma if it's possible.

Comment: +1 because it was the top Google answer for my search. It is a duplicate of the question mentioned by Sibshops however.

Comment: Questieon was about g++ but answer is about gcc. g++ gives me ignored pragmas for the selected answer

Comment: There's an ongoing bug for g++ https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53431